# $\log_7 n$ is either an integer or an irrational number

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

Show that   $\log_7 n$ is either an integer or an irrational number where n is a positive number.

I assumed that it is rational and tried to get a contradiction for $\log_7 n = a/b$, where b does not divide a, but how can I show that $7^{a/b}$ is not an integer to achieve a contradiction since n is an integer ? If I can exclude rational numbers from the range of log function then it is either integer or irrational.

Or do you suggest other methods ?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166441) as well.

Comment: As stated your statement is not true. For instance if $n=\sqrt{7}$, then $\log_7\sqrt{7}=\frac{1}{2}$. I think that you need $n$ to be a non-zero natural number.

Answer (score 9):

Interesting; usually one would assume not just that $b$ doesn't divide $a$ but that $a$ and $b$ are coprime, but in this case your assumption that $b$ doesn't divide $a$ is enough.

If $7^{a/b}=n$, then $7^a=n^b$. Thus $n$ must be a power of $7$, so we can write $n=7^k$ and thus $7^a=7^{kb}$, so $a=kb$, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: n must be a power of 7, can you prove this also ?

Comment: @mehdi: It follows from the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). Since the only prime in the prime factorization of $7^a$ is $7$ and prime factorizations are unique, $n^b$, and therefore $n$, can't contain any other primes.

Comment: Can you help to explain where exactly the contradiction is and what a = kb is contradicting?

Comment: @acw622: It contradicts the assumption that $b$ doesn't divide $a$. By definition $b$ divides $a$ iff there is an integer $k$ such that $a=kb$.