# If $(n_k)$ is strictly increasing and $\lim_{n \to \infty} n_k^{1/2^k} = \infty$ show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/n_k$ is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, problem-solving, irrational-numbers

> Prove that for a strictly increasing natural sequence $(n_k) $ satisfying $\lim_{n \to \infty} n_k^{1/2^k}=\infty$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/n_k$ is irrational.

This is another problem "problems in mathematical analysis" by Piotr and Witkowski. I've been trying to solve its problems for the last couple of days and I have thought about this one for a long time but nothing comes to my mind at all.

I can't even imagine how $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n_k^{1/2^k}=\infty$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/n_k$ could possibly be related to each other.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, $k$ must be a subscript, not a superscript. It's $n_k$, not $n^k$.

Comment: As far as how they could possibly be related, I think the point is that $n_k$ grows very fast, so fast that the reciprocal sum can't converge because each step makes it only a tiny bit larger than a rational number with a relatively tame denominator. I don't have a proof yet, though!

Comment: Perhaps Fouriers proof of the irrationality of $e$ can inspire you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational#Fourier.27s_proof

Comment: @Charles: I don't get the idea. How irrationality and the growth of a sequence can be related to each other? And What do you mean by "the recpirocal sum can't converge"? Isn't $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/n_k$ a convergent series or I'm missing something?

Comment: @barto: So, $e$ is irrational because it grows too fast for being a rational number. Am I right? So, in some sense, the condition $\lim_{n \to \infty} n_k^{1/2^k}$ is supposed to tell me that $n_k$ grows very very fast that even taking square roots of it infinitely many times doesn't stop its growth! Hmm, I'll try some ideas on this... Instead of $n!$, I should take the least common multiple of denominators I guess, but the rest is still very fuzzy for me!

Comment: @math.noob: No, that's exactly backwards. $e$ is irrational because the terms $\frac{1}{n!}$ _shrink_ too quickly for their sum to converge to a rational number.

Comment: Please add series tags :)

Comment: @TonyK: Yeah, but in this particular case in the problem $n_k$ is in the denominator, therefore $1/n_k$ shrinks. I was talking about the very fast growth of the denominator but I didn't make it clear enough, so you're right. So, the denominator grows very very fast and therefore the series gives too well approximations of $e$ that makes it impossible for $e$ to be rational. I remember there was a theorem that said you can't approximate a rational number by rational numbers so well, I guess it was due to Liouville if I'm not mistaken. It's similar to this case somehow, right?

Comment: @Julien: I added it, but I don't see why that tag is needed. This problem isn't about convergence of a series, radius of convergence or calculation of the limit of a series.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792583

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/n_k=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are strictly positive integer,

Then,
$$
n_1n_2\cdots n_{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}1/n_{k+j}\geq \frac{1}{q}
$$
for $k\geq 2$.

Now let $a_k=n_k^{\frac{1}{2^k}}$, by hypothesis $\lim_{n \to \infty} n_k^{1/2^k}=+\infty$

Therefore there exist $r_1$ such that $a_j\leq a_{r_1}$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,r_1-1$

Indeed, if $a_1\leq a_2$, $r_1=2$,

If this is not the case, we chooses the smallest integer $r_1>2$ such that $a_1\leq a_{r_1}$.

There are actually a whole infinite sequence $r_k$ checking the above property, that is to say such as,
$$
a_j\leq a_{r_k}, \quad j=1,2,\cdots,r_k-1
$$

To find $r_2$, the above procedure is applied to the following sequence $\{a_k\}_{k \geq r_1}$, and so forth.

We denote $r$ the smallest positive integer such that $a_{r+j}>q+1$ for $j\in \mathbb{N}$
and $a_j \leq a_r$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,r-1$.

Since, $n_r \leq n_{r+j}$  we have $a_r \leq a_{r+j}^{\large 2^j}$ 
$$
\frac{n_1n_2\cdots n_{r-1}}{n_{r+j}} \leq \frac{a_r^{\large 2+2^2+\cdots+2^{r-1}}}{n_{r+j}}\leq  \frac{a_{r+j}^{\large 2^{j}(2^r-2)}}{a_{r+j}^{\large 2^{r+j}}}=a_{r+j}^{\large -2^{j+1}}<(q+1)^{-(j+1)}
$$

Thus,

$$
n_1n_2\cdots n_{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}1/n_{r+j}<\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(q+1)^{-(j+1)}=\frac{1}{q}
$$
Contradiction $\square$

---

Addendum  : For the intuition behind the exercise, try this :

Let $\{n_k\}$ a sequence of strictly positive integer such that 
$$
\limsup_{k\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n_k}{n_1n_2\cdots n_{k-1}}=+\infty, \quad \liminf_{k\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n_k}{n_{k-1}}>1
$$
Show that 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_{i}}
$$
is irrational.

To prove it, assume $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/n_k=\frac{p}{q}$ and write
$$
\sum_{k=k_1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n_k}=\frac{p}{q}-\sum_{k=1}^{k_1-1} \frac{1}{n_k}
$$

- What can you say about $\sum_{k=k_1}^{\infty} \frac{q n_1n_2\cdots n_{k-1}}{n_k}$ ?

Then the intuition behind my first inequality follow.

For the remainder of the proof, I will leave it to you (as planned).

Comment: Interesting. The main step that makes the assumption that the limit is rational ridiculous seems to be the first inequality, being a very sharp upper bound due to the rationality. The intuition behind the rest of your proof is still a bit vague to me, perhaps you could tell how you found this?

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem too. I'm trying to analyze your proof, but there are still some ideas in it that are vague and I'm trying to work them out. This is an awesome proof but if you explain how the idea came to you that would make it even more awesome.

Comment: @math.n00b I had already done an another exercice which is similar and easier, I'll add it if you want but I leave the proof to you. Please ask if after working on it, you still have questions.

Comment: Yes, that would be a great practice for me if you add  the exercise. Honestly I'm still struggling with your first inequality but I'm trying to understand why it's true, I'll keep on trying to find out the reason on my own before I ask you. Thanks.

Comment: @math.n00b You are welcome, I have add it with some details. I hope you will succeed :)

Comment: Is there a way to reword the exercise without limsup and liminf? Because I haven't studied them yet.

Comment: @math.n00b look at wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior